# Visual Studio 2015 crash on startup - Possibly licensing-related

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crash, startup

My apologies if this is a duplicate - I have searched for identical questions but did not find any.

I recently updated to VS 2015 professional SP 2, and any attempt to open VS after this point results in an immediate crash. I have pasted the error details below.

I have tried reinstalling VS, running devenv with the various /ResetSkipPkgs, /ResetSettings, /SafeMode flags and have had no change in behavior. I am able to run VS Ultimate 2013 with no problems.

Exception details (with some manual formatting for readability):

```
Application: devenv.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
Exception Info: System.NotSupportedException at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.UserInformation.UserInformationDataSource.get_VsLicensingState() at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.UserInformation.UserInformationDataSource.SignInAndCheckForLicenseAsync(System.Object) at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.UserInformation.UserInformationDataSource.UserInformationCommandHandler(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIDispatch, System.String, System.Object, System.Object ByRef) at 
Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.UIDispatch.Invoke(System.String, System.Object, System.Object ByRef) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.UserInformation.UserInformationDataSource.PrepareForFirstLaunchSignIn() at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.UserInformation.UserInformationDataSource.UserInformationCommandHandler(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIDispatch, System.String, System.Object, System.Object ByRef) at 
Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.UIDispatch.Invoke(System.String, System.Object, System.Object ByRef) at 
Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DataSource.Invoke(System.String, System.Object, System.Object ByRef) at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.UserInformation.FirstLaunchSignIn.FirstLaunchSignIn_Loaded(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) at 
System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) at 
System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean) at 
System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) at 
System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) at 
System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEvent) at 
System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(System.Object) at 
MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork() at 
System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks() at 
System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks() at 
System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(System.Object) at 
System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(System.Object) at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Resize(System.Windows.Media.ICompositionTarget) at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize() at 
System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr) at 
System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at 
MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object) at 
System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at 
System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) at 
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr) at 
MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DefWndProcWrapper(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr) at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

Any assistance resolving this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Performing a Repair of

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 with Updates

from Control Panel> Programs> Programs and Features fixed this for me.